# removing a return statement from the loop

Tags: java

please i want to removed the returmn statement from the loop and have only one return statement at the end of the loop for the two method.

```
   private boolean productFitsAt(int lOrigin, int wOrigin, int[] product) {
    for (int i = wOrigin; i < wOrigin + product[Data.WID]; i++) {
        for (int j = lOrigin; j < lOrigin + product[Data.LEN]; j++) {
            if (i >= BOX_WIDTH || j >= BOX_LENGHT || BOX[i][j] != EMPTY) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

  private boolean putProductIntoBox(int[] product) {
    int[] a = getFreePositionToFit(product);
    if (a == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (maxWeight < product[Data.WT]) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = a[0]; i < a[0] + product[Data.WID]; i++) {
        for (int j = a[1]; j < a[1] + product[Data.LEN]; j++) {
            BOX[i][j] = product[Data.ID];
        }
    }
    maxWeight -= product[Data.WT];
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Just select the `return false;` text and press your delete key then

Answer (score 2):

I would label the outer loop and break out of it once the `result` is assigned `false`, e.g.:

```
private boolean productFitsAt(int lOrigin, int wOrigin, int[] product) {
    boolean result = true;
    outer :for (int i = wOrigin; i < wOrigin + product[Data.WID]; i++) {
            for (int j = lOrigin; j < lOrigin + product[Data.LEN]; j++) {
                if (i >= BOX_WIDTH || j >= BOX_LENGHT || BOX[i][j] != EMPTY) {
                    result = false;
                    break outer;
                }
            }
        }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I vcant use a break either

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `boolean` variable to store the return value, and return that variable at the end of the method:

```
private boolean productFitsAt(int lOrigin, int wOrigin, int[] product) {
    boolean result = true;
    for (int i = wOrigin; i < wOrigin + product[Data.WID] && result; i++) {
        for (int j = lOrigin; j < lOrigin + product[Data.LEN] && result; j++) {
            if (i >= BOX_WIDTH || j >= BOX_LENGHT || BOX[i][j] != EMPTY) {
                result = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that once you determine the return value is `false`, you don't want to continue the loops. Since you have nested loops, a break statement won't be enough (since it will only break out of the inner loop), so I added the `result` variable to the condition of both loops.

Comment: Why would you want the loop to continue the execution once it's decided that result is going to be `false`?

Comment: @DarshanMehta I just fixed that.

Comment: This answer is inefficient and performs worse than OP's original solution.

Comment: @tobias_k Nope, the break is not enough, so I used a different solution.

Comment: @DarshanMehta The answer does what the OP wanted, which is to have a single return statement at the end.

Comment: Ah, now I see. +1. Still, I think keeping that `return` in place is the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could also convert your nested loop into a nested `allMatch` or `anyMatch` statement using Java 8 Streams. Note that when using `allMatch` you have to invert the conditions:

```
private boolean productFitsAt(int lOrigin, int wOrigin, int[] product) {
    return IntStream.range(wOrigin, wOrigin + product[Data.WID])
            .allMatch(i -> IntStream.range(lOrigin, lOrigin + product[Data.LEN])
                    .allMatch(j -> (i < BOX_WIDTH && j < BOX_LENGTH && BOX[i][j] == EMPTY)));
}
```

Comment: i not suppose to use A stream

Comment: @Helen You are not "supposed" to use multiple `return`, or `break`, or `Stream`... maybe it would be faster to tell us what you _can_ use instead.